A Method which runs every second? in Android Studio
Is there a way to create a method in java which will run every second?
I want to check if my ToggleButton is checked every second and if checked then vibrate the device.
In the below code, tb is ToggleButton.
I want to make it so that the below code runs every second and checks if the ToggleButton is checked or not.
if(tb.isChecked()){
    if(checkSelfPermission(PERMISSION_VIBRATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted to vibrate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(curhour == hour && curmin == minutes){
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(500);
        }

I tried recursion and calling the method again at the end of the code but then the app crashes for some reason.

You can register a listener to find out when the state of the button is changed. That would be much more efficient and effective than polling the button every second.

Given your logic in the "isChecked" code to check for a specific hour and minute of the day to vibrate (with conditions), this sounds like a job for the AlarmManager which schedules work at a specific time of day.   The work performed would include the "isChecked" condition.  Also, better describe what happens at the moment; vibrate for the entire minute?


Define Permissions: Ensure you have the necessary permissions
declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file to use the vibrator
service.

Create a Handler and Runnable: Use a Handler to post a Runnable that
checks the state of the ToggleButton every second.

Check ToggleButton State: Inside the Runnable, check if the
ToggleButton is checked. If it is, proceed to vibrate the device.

Vibrate Device: Use the Vibrator system service to vibrate the
device if the conditions are met.
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Vibrator;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_VIBRATE = 100;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnableCode;
private ToggleButton tb; // Assuming tb is already initialized

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tb = findViewById(R.id.your_toggle_button_id); // Initialize 
       your ToggleButton here

    runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(tb.isChecked()) {
                int curhour = // get current hour
                int curmin = // get current minutes
                int hour = // set desired hour
                int minutes = // set desired minutes

                if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.VIBRATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission granted to vibrate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(curhour == hour && curmin == minutes){
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(500);
                    }
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.VIBRATE},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_VIBRATE);
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // Repeat every second
        }
    };

    startRepeatingTask();
}

private void startRepeatingTask() {
    handler.post(runnableCode);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopRepeatingTask();
}

private void stopRepeatingTask() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_VIBRATE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission granted to vibrate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission denied to vibrate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}}



